# How is it possible for ARP-entry to be removed at router for a device in active use?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, arp

Specifically, this applies to an Apple-Tv-3 over wifi. The Apple-Tv was in use from 9.15 to 11.00pm, all the time streaming from Youtube or some other service.

The ARP-entry at the router for the Apple Tv's mac and IP (seen by using the command arp -a) had been removed around 9.30pm and then restored around 10.30pm. All this time the Apple TV was in continuous use. No stutters or stops and 3 different streaming services (including Youtube) were used (through the built-in apps, no Airplay involved) during this time.

No spoofing had occurred as both the IP address and MAC of the ATV had been removed entirely for this 1 hour. No new devices had been added during this period. The DHCP entries were also unchanged.

How is this possible? I thought a valid ARP entry - specifically at the router - would be essential to the operation of the network itself!

Comment: Do you have IPv6 internet access?

Comment: No it's ipv4 - afaik based on the IP address assigned by the ISP etc. Do you mean IPV6 Internal to the network? Not that I know of. How do you think I should find out? For one Ive never seen IPV6 addresses in the DHCP list of the router front-end or in the actual DHCP tables. And even in that case, would ARP tables not reflect an IPV6 style ip-addeess? Perhaps I'm jumping many guns here. Pls let me know your line of thought.

Comment: IPv6 doesn't use ARP (and usually doesn't use DHCP either), and in fact that's exactly why I'm asking about it.